# Getting the infinitive from a conjugated verb

Tags: dictionary, conjugation

Is there a way in an online dictionary such as dict.cc to find the infinitive of a conjugated verb?  For instance, searching for 'trifft' or 'traf', how could I tell it was from 'treffen'?  Or how to tell that a verb is separable, for instance that 'trifft zu' comes from 'zutreffen', instead of a commonly used preposition such as 'gehen zu'.

Comment: Every online dictionary provides this. dict.cc, leo.dict.org, pons.eu, wiktionary, ... Each of these dictionaries shows the information you need if you search for a conjugated form. And most of them additionally offer a link to a full conjugation table.

Comment: I see what you mean about the conjugation table.  On dict.cc, this is above traf, but not trifft and, therefore, not above trifft zu.

Comment: Don't expect to find a single source which can do everything. I would suggest using dict.leo.org. If you search for "trifft" or "trifft zu" you'll find "treffen" or "zutreffen", respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are free to use dictionary sites like [Pons](http://de.pons.com/) that will find both [trifft](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=trifft&l=deen&in=&lf=) and [traf](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=traf&l=deen&in=&lf=).

It's usually not a problem to indentify the prefix of a seperable verb, because unlike a preposition it won't be followed by a noun. So you get `"Das trifft zu"`, but `"Ich gehe zum Bäcker"`.

Comment: Ah, yeah. That makes sense about the noun following the preposition.  If it's separable, the prefix will (always?) be moved to the end of the phrase/sentence.  I didn't mark this as the answer because it doesn't really explain where to find the infinitive.

Comment: @MrUser: Well, if you look up the conjugated form it will show you the infinitive. Not sure if this works for all conjugated forms and all verbs, give it a try. Yes, the prefix of a seperable verb will always be moved to the very end of a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu) - they have conjugation tables for a lot of verbs.

Comment: Well, it's not really a language question, but about tools. What explanation is there supposed to be? Or am I talking to a bot?

Comment: Probably dict.cc's anticompetition bot.